# Docker make multiple ips of host machine available to a container (docker compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a server with multiple ipv4's and want to make http requests inside of a docker container that use these different ip's as `localAdress`. How can i expose these ips to the specific docker service in docker compose?

Comment: Is the server a Linux machine?

Comment: When you say "expose these IPs", what operation are you trying to perform?  How would you use these addresses if Docker weren't involved?  Do you have any application code or other parts of a [mcve] that might help illustrate the problem?